# Doubts on the setting of PMA Rudin's proof of the 9.24 (Inverse Function Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

PMA Rudin Theorem 9.24 (Inverse Function Theorem)

Suppose $\textbf{f}$ is a $\mathscr{C '}$-mapping of an open set $E \subset R^n$ into $ R^n. \textbf{f '(a)}$ is invertible for some $\textbf{a} \in E$, and $\textbf{b = f (a)}$. Then:

(a) There exist open sets $U$ and $V$ in $R^n$ such that $\textbf{a} \in U, \textbf{b} \in V$. $\textbf{f}$ is one-to-one on U, and $\textbf{f}(U)=V$;

(b) If $\textbf{g}$ is the inverse of $\textbf{f}$ [which exists, by (a)], defined in $V$ by $\textbf{g(f(x))} = \textbf{x}$, (for $\textbf{x} \in U)$. Then $\textbf{g} \in \mathscr{C '}(V)$

---

For part b of his proof on the book, the first line states: "Pick $\textbf{y} \in V, \; \textbf{y} + \textbf{k} \in V$. Then there exist $\textbf{x} \in U, \; \textbf{x + h} \in U,$ so that $\textbf{y} = \textbf{f(x)}, \; \textbf{y + k = f(x + h)}.$"

**Question 1:** Is it okay to assume that open sets $U$ and $V$ as vector spaces. Is this assumption arbitrary or common sense ?

Comment: This is a restatement of openness of $U$ and $V$, and continuity of $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: Maybe the part about $y$ and $k$ would be easier to understand if it were phrased as: Pick two points $y,z\in V$. Let $k=z-y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I understand that f is continuous, U and V are open and so for the first line of proof (part b), it is using the fact that f is a bijection between U and V.  Such that k and h are arbitrary vectors that allows the declaration of another point distinct from x and y. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

$U,V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space,  but $U,V$ aren't in general. For them to be, it'd be necessary that for all $x \in U$ and $q \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $qx \in U$ also: similar with $V$. However, we can still do addition and scalar multiplication with elements of $U,V$: the outputs will definitely be in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but not necessarily in $U,V$.
It's easier to think of $U,V$ as balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$, eg at any point $x \in U$, we can move a little bit any direction and remain in $U$.